# Cross platform apps and programing languages...how is it done?

Tags: programming-languages, operating-systems

I always wondered how various certain languages like Java, HTML5 and browser extensions are made with cross platform(operates and functions the same, regardless of OS, being Linux/Windows/BSD not specifically CPU architecture)  compatibility in mind...

Is there a certain developmental process semantic or otherwise that one would have to follow, in order to create such?

Can some one give me the "nitty gritty" of how it's done , how  it works ... i.e. system calls(if any)

Comment: Summarizing the answers: Abstraction.

Comment: actually for anyone involved in web development and javascript in particular, HTML5 is an example of frequent cross-platform incompatibility across browsers. part of the difficulty is lack/inherent inability to create automated tests across browser platforms.

Answer (score 5):

First word: consistent API across platforms - when programming on different platforms, the same API is presented to programmers.

Second word: layered architecture - this hides the low level differences under a consistent layer.

Answer (score 4):

In many cases, Java being a prominent example, the code is interpreted by a virtual machine. The virtual machine is different for each operating system, but they all provide the same functionality, so that the Java code does not see the difference. This is also true for HTML, Javascript, Python, Ruby and many more.

On the other hand, it is possible to write cross platform code in languages that don't have a virtual machine, like C. Here the code only uses the parts of the operating system interface that are the same among all platforms, for example it can stick to the POSIX standard to run smoothly under all unix flavours and (with a little luck?) windows. However, while the code is platform-independent, it needs to be recompiled for each platform so that it can be linked with the concrete libraries that the operating system provides and adhere to the encoding scheme for executables used on that platform.

In both cases a layer of abstraction separates the codes and the operating system. In the first case it's the API provided by the virtual machine, in the second case it's a layer of libraries that provide the same interface across platforms. If code performs syscalls "by hand" it usually is no longer platform-independent (unless it checks on which platform it runs and does different things in each case, of course).

Answer (score 1):

Standardization certainly plays an important role. Specifications can be implemented differently but you can expect the final product to correctly implement the MUST's, SHOULD's, ... of the spec.

Answer (score 0):

This cross-platform consistency is mainly permitted by standardization of various platform features, so that they offer the same behavior independently of how the feature is actually implemented ón each platform.

But on the other hand, this is precisely the reason why standardization is actively worked on and reinforced: to get compatibility. Standardization, platform independence and compatibility (what is often called interoperability) are developed for many reasons, and it shows from the kind of actors who work on it.

If you consider the Internet, it is primarily a mean for communication. If there is no agreement on what can be exchanged and what it means, there is just no communication. Man communicates poorly with dolphins for hardware reasons, and often poorly with other men for software reasons.

Companies want cross-platform compatibility to have larger market for their products, so as to benefit from economy of scale. Companies have to follow the existing standards if they want their products to be accepted by market.

All this converges.

From an abstract point of view, computers are supposed to be universal machines, even with the OS fixed. So there is no surprise that this is possible, and that it happens since it is useful, including for business.

Think of what people do when they mimic Turing machnes of one kind with another kind. It is much the same idea, except that you are more concerned with efficiency which often requires ingenuity. This is why virtual machines hosting full OSs took a long time to develop. In comparison, developing HTML on all platforms was very easy.

And there is also the fact that the determination of (good) standards is done (technically, and hopefully politically) with the idea that they should be realizable on all concerned platforms.

The real problems arise when people (usually companies) try to control standards. The technical problems are easy (they do require work). The hard problems are legal, social, economic ones.

What do you do when you are told that a given interface is private and that you must pay for using it ? or that you are simply not allowed to use it ? Think of CODECs for example.